# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get' odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

I have model which contains:
name , group
for group i have from group 1 to 9
then in another model i create many2one from model one:

```
 request_l = fields.Many2one('model.one',
                                         string='Model Name',
                                    
                                         required=True,
                                         store=True)
```

then i create function to fill the selection based on choice of request_l

```
        @api.model
        @api.onchange('request_l')
        def _populate_choice(self):
            choices = [
            ]
            if self.requst_l.group == 'g1':
                    choices += [('user', 'User'), ('manager', 'Manager')]
            return choices

        type_g = fields.Selection(string='Type', selection=_populate_choice, default='', store=True, )
```

but it shows error at this line :

**if self.requst_l.group == 'g1':**

```
if res.get('value'):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: `group` field should be of type `Char`, ``Text``, `Selection` or `Html` else you need to update the `if` statement depending on the field type.

Answer (score 0):

`res` variable is a `list`. As a `list` it does not have the `get` method built in. You could access its contents with integer subscripts:

```
print(str(res[0]))
```

You are trying to access its data as if it was a `dict`. But it's not. If you have an IDE and a DEBUGGER, you could inspect what's in `res` right on your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

in my case removing @api.one solves the problem, probably you can try removing @api.model, leave only @api.onchange.